# UITextView startInteractionWithLinkAtPoint crash iOS 11 only

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, ios11

So I experience crash in UItextview while user interacts with URL link there. All crash reports have iOS version 11 only.
This looks like well-known bug in iOS 9, but there is no single report iOS versions lower than 11, and also in report I found interesting line:

```
UITextGestureClusterLinkInteract smallDelayRecognizer:
```

which came with iOS 11 (http://developer.limneos.net/?ios=11.0&framework=UIKit.framework&header=UITextGestureClusterLinkInteract.h).
Anyway, for now I fixed it with

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL)
    return false
}
```

which is not so cool, because you lose action sheet menu. 
My assumption was that it is caused by 3D touch (like by long press in previous versions), but if I detect 3D touch (75%, or even 50% of maximum force) and disable link interaction for this specific gesture - issue still appears.
Does anybody has some experience with this particular issue and more elegance way of solving it?

Comment: Same issue here. If you have solved it please inform me

Comment: @Cœur Nice Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A crash is caused by a `UIDragInteraction`/`UITextDragAssistant` on iOS 11.0 and 11.1. It is fixed on iOS 11.2. Subclassing your UITextView and disabling drag and drop gestures will prevent the crash for any iOS version:

```
class NoDragDropTextView: UITextView {

    override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        // required to prevent drag and drop gestures
        // also prevents a crash on iOS 11.0-11.1
        gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false

        super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced and solved this problem.

This is workaround in my production code. Disable interaction `.preview` state because of crashes only this state occurs.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    switch interaction {
    case .presentActions, .invokeDefaultAction:
        return handleLinkURL(url: URL)
    case .preview:
        return false
    }
}
```