# iOS crash: -[UITextView(LinkInteraction) startInteractionWithLinkAtPoint:]

Tags: ios, crash, uitextview

According to crashlytics, a few users are experiencing crashes on the following line

```
-[UITextView(LinkInteraction) startInteractionWithLinkAtPoint:]
```

I can't replicate it at all. This might be an iOS 11 issue because that seems to be version it is crashing on.

Here is the complete crash log.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1849fed8c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x183bb85ec objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1849febf8 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x1853eefa0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x18f2daf3c -[UITextView(LinkInteraction) startInteractionWithLinkAtPoint:]
5  UIKit                          0x18ed4597c -[UITextGestureClusterLinkInteract smallDelayRecognizer:]
6  UIKit                          0x18e7ea6e8 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:]
7  UIKit                          0x18ed573b4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions
8  UIKit                          0x18e94ce38 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
9  UIKit                          0x18e7e9720 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
10 UIKit                          0x18ed48bd4 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate
11 UIKit                          0x18e7e34d8 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:]
12 UIKit                          0x18e7e3010 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:]
13 UIKit                          0x18e7e2874 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
14 UIKit                          0x18e7e11d0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
15 UIKit                          0x18efc2d1c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
16 UIKit                          0x18efc52c8 __handleEventQueueInternal
17 UIKit                          0x18efbe368 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1849a7404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1849a6c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1849a479c __CFRunLoopRun
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1848c4da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
22 GraphicsServices               0x1868a9020 GSEventRunModal
23 UIKit                          0x18e8e1758 UIApplicationMain
24 MyApp                          0x10441cc88 main (main.m:14)
25 libdyld.dylib                  0x184355fc0 start
```

I've seen this stackoverflow post

> [UITextView startInteractionWithLinkAtPoint crash iOS 11 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732546/uitextview-startinteractionwithlinkatpoint-crash-ios-11-only/49535011)

However, I don't want to disable drag and drop. Should I wait until Apple fixes this issue because this seems to be a bug on Apple's end.

Comment: Also happening on iOS 12 - did you find a fix?